Gentoo linux -- add uinput module to kernel
I am trying to implement copy/paste from host openSUSE to guest Gentoo VM. I have installed spice-vdagent on the host and the guest. vdagent will not start on the Gentoo guest as it says uinput kernel module is needed.
Cannot find detailed instructions needed to install uinput either as builtin to kernel or as a separate accessible module.
Any advice?

Are you using a pre-built kernel or did you build it yourself?

compiling kernel myself; not pre-built binary.

If you want to add support for uinput to your kernel, you can do the following (as root):
# cd /usr/src/linux
# make menuconfig

Press / to search and type uinput and press enter, you'll see something like:
  │ Symbol: INPUT_UINPUT [=n]                                                                                                                             │
  │ Type  : tristate                                                                                                                                      │
  │ Defined at drivers/input/misc/Kconfig:534                                                                                                             │
  │   Prompt: User level driver support                                                                                                                   │
  │   Depends on: INPUT [=y] && INPUT_MISC [=n]                                                                                                           │
  │   Location:                                                                                                                                           │
  │     -> Device Drivers                                                                                                                                 │
  │       -> Input device support                                                                                                                         │
  │         -> Generic input layer (needed for keyboard, mouse, ...) (INPUT [=y])                                                                         │
  │ (1)       -> Miscellaneous devices (INPUT_MISC [=n])                                                                                                  │
  │             -> User level driver support (INPUT_UINPUT [=n])                                                                                      │
  │                                                                                                                                                       │

If INPUT_MISC isn't enabled (as in this case in the above example), you'll need to enable it.  Press the number to the left (here 1).
Press spacebar to enable it:
  │ [*]   Miscellaneous devices  ---> 

Press / to search and type uniput (again) and press enter.  You'll see something like:
  │ Symbol: INPUT_UINPUT [=n]                                                                                                                             │
  │ Type  : tristate                                                                                                                                      │
  │ Defined at drivers/input/misc/Kconfig:534                                                                                                             │
  │   Prompt: User level driver support                                                                                                                   │
  │   Depends on: INPUT [=y] && INPUT_MISC [=y]                                                                                                           │
  │   Location:                                                                                                                                           │
  │     -> Device Drivers                                                                                                                                 │
  │       -> Input device support                                                                                                                         │
  │         -> Generic input layer (needed for keyboard, mouse, ...) (INPUT [=y])                                                                         │
  │           -> Miscellaneous devices (INPUT_MISC [=y])                                                                                                  │
  │ (1)         -> User level driver support (INPUT_UINPUT [=n])                                                                                      │

Press the number to the left of INPUT_UINPUT (here 1)
Press the spacebar. You can build it as a module:
  <M>   User level driver support

or press the spacebar again to build it into the kernel binary image:
  <*>   User level driver support

Repeated select Exit until you are prompted to saved the updated configuration.
Finally, rebuild/reinstall your kernel (and/or modules) following the same instructions you followed to build them initially.

I followed your detailed instructions and was successful.  vdagent now does start and copy/paste to gentoo vm now works.  Thank you for your excellent instructions.
